# Dynamically create buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically create some buttons from a database in javascript, however, each button is created with the correct innerHTML but each has the same onClick event.

Each button has the onClick event the last button should have.

```
        var counter = 0;
        var name = "";
        var buttonAmount = 0;
        data.Result.forEach(function(o) 
        {
            name = data.Result[counter].buttonName;
            buttonAmount = data.Result[counter].buttonAmount;
            buttonAmount = Number(buttonAmount);
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerHTML = name;
            button.onclick = function(){
                total(buttonAmount);
            }
            document.body.append(button);
            counter ++;
            console.log(buttonAmount);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that buttonAmount is scoped to the outer block, so all references to it will reference the same number/value. Declare buttonAmount inside the forEach block instead:

```
data.Result.forEach(function(o) {
  const name = data.Result[counter].buttonName;
  const buttonAmount = Number(data.Result[counter].buttonAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you declare `var buttonAmount = 0;` outside the array iteration which is in global scope, the above statement need to put inside the `data.Result.forEach(function(o)` which is the local scope.

```
    var counter = 0;
    var name = ""; 

    //var buttonAmount = 0; **Remove from here**

    data.Result.forEach(function(o) 
    {
        var buttonAmount = 0;// Add here
        name = data.Result[counter].buttonName;
        buttonAmount = data.Result[counter].buttonAmount;
        buttonAmount = Number(buttonAmount);
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = name;
        button.onclick = function(){
            total(buttonAmount);
        }
        document.body.append(button);
        counter ++;
        console.log(buttonAmount);
    });
```